# Buttons blank when Windows Forms application is started

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I open my Windows Forms application for the first time some of the buttons do not render correctly, when the form is move slightly they appear.

See below.

[image: before]

after dragging the form they appear.

[image: after]

This is my startup code.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    bool createdNew = true;

    using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "Support_Desk_System", out createdNew))
    {
        if (createdNew)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            GC.KeepAlive(mutex);
        }
        else
        {
            Process current = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName))
            {
                if (process.Id != current.Id)
                {
                    SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not a major issue just annoying because i have no idea why it's happening.

This is the form code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.status_CodesTableAdapter.Fill(this.supportDeskDataSet.Status_Codes);
        this.systemsTableAdapter.Fill(this.supportDeskDataSet.Systems);
        this.cases_Quick_ViewTableAdapter.Fill(this.supportDeskDataSet.Cases_Quick_View);
        this.dataGridView1.DoubleBuffered(true);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {    
            if (Myrow.Cells[7].Value.ToString() == "High")
            {
                Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            if(Myrow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "Back Burner")
            {
                Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
    }
}
public static class DataGridViewExtensioncs
{
    public static void DoubleBuffered(this DataGridView dgv, bool setting)
    {
        var dgvType = dgv.GetType();
        var pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is in that code...are you doing anything in your form's constructor or `Load` event?

Comment: I agree with @Pikoh . However you Main method looks suspiciously. Are you sure, the branch with SetForegroundWindow is correct?

Comment: I don't think it is @TcKs, it should be something like `if (Process.GetProcessesByName(current.ProcessName).Any()) {SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle); `. But it's unrelated with the questions :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that doing too much in dataGridView1_CellFormatting causes the problem.

I scaled the code down to :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow Myrow in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {    
        if (Myrow.Cells[7].Value.ToString() == "High")
        {
            Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        //else
        //{
        //  Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        //}
        if(Myrow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "Back Burner")
        {
            Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            Myrow.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}
```

and set the default row colour to Green instead and now it works without issue.

Comment: You don't have to do a foreach in the `CellFormatting` event. That is probably the problem. In `DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs` you get the row that is being processed, and that's the one you need to change. This obviously would slow down the grid